# Повторная отправка формы, как исправить? php

Tags: php, sql, form

Всем привет, я делаю чат(форум) и при обновлении страницы выводится ещё одно сообщение, идентичное последнему отправленному сообщению.
Вот код:

```
<?php
    $connect = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=*****;charset=UTF8", '*******', '***');
    if (isset($_POST['username'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        $date = date('H:i:s');
        $query = $connect->query("INSERT INTO *****.comments (username, comment, data) VALUES ('$username', '$comment', '$date'");
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Форум</h2>
<div class="block">
<?
    $comments = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM *****.comments ORDER BY data DESC");
    $comments = $comments->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($comments){
        foreach($comments as $comment){
?>
            <p><?="{$comment['data']} . {$comment['username']}"?> :</p>
            <br>
            <p><?="{$comment['comment']}"?></p>
            <br>
<div class="line"></div>
<?
        }
    }else{
        echo "Пока нет ни одного комментария :(";
    }
?>
</div>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="block-comment">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Ваше имя" required>
        <textarea name="comment" cols="10" rows="5" placeholder="Ваш комментарий" required></textarea>
        <input type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
<style font-size=""></style>
</body>
</html>
```

Помогите пожалуйста.
Вот ссылка сайта: forum-dvoryashin.ru

Comment: Так и должно быть, вы же отправляете форму и обновляет её запрос

Answer (score 0):

Используй header.

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $date = date('H:i:s');
    $query = $connect->query("INSERT INTO *****.comments (username, comment, data) VALUES ('$username', '$comment', '$date'");
header('Location: index.php'); //укажи нужную страницу
exit();
}
```

Почитай про header тут: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php

Comment: header указал, но теперь сообщения просто не отправляются